# How to convert Django Modelfield choice string to value

Tags: python, django

Suppose, I have the following Django model:

```
class myModel(models.Model):
    C = "myC"
    D = "myD"

    A = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=False, blank=False,)
    B = models.CharField(
        max_length=254,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        choices=((C, "C"), (D, "D")),
    )

    def set_B(self, choice_val):
        self.B = #WHAT GOES HERE??
        self.save()
```

Now suppose I create an object `X` of type myModel.
Then I call `X.set_B("D")`. I want the `set_B()` method of myModel to set the value of `B` to `myModel.D`. How can I do that? What code do I have to put in `set_B()` such that it converts the human readable value "D" to `myModel.D`?

Comment: What is `C` in `(C, "C"), (D, "D")` because you keep saying `myModel.D` as if `D` is a property of `myModel`, yet I do not see it declared anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the `getattr` funtion.

```
class myModel(models.Model):

A = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=False, blank=False,)
B = models.CharField(
    max_length=254,
    null=False,
    blank=False,
    choices=((C, "C"), (D, "D")),
)
C = #Something
D = #Something

def set_B(self, choice_val):
    self.B = getattr(self,choice_val)
    self.save()
```

The `getattr` function will return the value of the choice_val attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You could construct a look-up `dict` at the class level and use that:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    B_CHOICES = ((C, "C"), (D, "D"))
    B_VALUES_FROM_NAME = {name: val for val, name in B_CHOICES}
    B = models.CharField(
        max_length=254,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        choices=B_CHOICES,
    )

    def set_B(self, name):
        self.B = MyModel.B_VALUES_FROM_NAME[name]
        self.save()
```